# Point exist in circle

Tags: sql, sql-server, math, geometry

Let us consider `(x,y)` is a point and then make a `radius` of some value `r`.  If suppose I had a point `(a,b)`, I need to check whether `(a,b)` is within the circle centered as `(x,y)` or not.

How can I achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 <= r^2

Comment: @CharlesBretana He is asking for a SQL query, ill give you that its off-topic as he hasn't supplied anything that he's tried himself.

Comment: Thank you,I need sql query only.

Comment: @Ashley,  Not that it's important, but I disagree.  Whatever he says now, He did NOT ask for the SQL query. He asked for the formula, so that he can *implement* it as a SQL query.  At best, he mis-stated his question...

Comment: @CharlesBretana - I'm voting to reopen as I'd quite like to see a solution to this that uses the SQL Server geometry types (just out of interest). I had a go with `CIRCULARSTRING` ... `STContains` ... `POINT` but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Martin,  I will take a hack at it as well.. It will be fun as I have not used the geometry types as yet...

Comment: There's a bunch of similar questions all over SO, so this should probably be changed to a duplicate.  Although question for the OP - is this over the surface of a sphere (like say, the earth), or a near-plane (local distances only)?  There are two _very_ different formulas to use.

Comment: @CharlesBretana - Ah I know where I was going wrong now. `CIRCULARSTRING` just defines the line. `CURVEPOLYGON` defines the shape. For a circle with radius `3` at `(4,4)` you could use `SELECT geometry::STGeomFromText('CURVEPOLYGON(CIRCULARSTRING(4 1, 7 4, 4 7, 1 4, 4 1))', 0 ).STContains(geometry::STPointFromText('POINT (4 4)', 0 ))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (x NUMERIC(10,2), y NUMERIC(10,2), radius NUMERIC(10,2))
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES (3.5,3.5, 5.5),(20.5,20.5, 10.5), (30.5,30.5, 20.5)
```

**Query**

```
DECLARE @p1 NUMERIC(10,2) = 5.5   --<-- Point to check
DECLARE @p2 NUMERIC(10,2) = 5.5


SELECT *, CASE WHEN POWER( @p1 - x, 2) + POWER( @p2 - y, 2) <= POWER(radius, 2)
             THEN 'Inside The Circle'
            WHEN POWER( @p1 - x, 2) + POWER( @p2 - y, 2) > POWER(radius, 2)
             THEN 'Outside the Circle' END   [Inside/Outside]
FROM @t
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦════════╦════════════════════╗
║   x   ║   y   ║ radius ║   Inside/Outside   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬════════╬════════════════════╣
║ 3.50  ║ 3.50  ║ 5.50   ║ Inside The Circle  ║
║ 20.50 ║ 20.50 ║ 10.50  ║ Outside the Circle ║
║ 30.50 ║ 30.50 ║ 20.50  ║ Outside the Circle ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩════════╩════════════════════╝
```

As question was closed, could not add another answer, so I edited this to include solution using Sql Server `Geometry` types... [Uses same data points as above, plus one to demo exactly on the circle]

```
Declare @t TABLE 
   (x NUMERIC(10,2), y NUMERIC(10,2), 
    radius NUMERIC(10,2))
Insert @t
Values (3.5,3.5, 5.5),(20.5,20.5, 10.5), 
       (30.5,30.5, 20.5), (-5.5, 5.5, 11.0)

-- --------------------------
Declare @pX float = 5.5    
Declare @pY float = 5.5
Declare @c geometry;
Declare @p geometry;
Select x, y, radius, 
      (geometry::Point(X, Y, 0)).STDistance(geometry::Point(@pX, @pY, 0))
From @T
Where (geometry::Point(X, Y, 0)).STDistance(geometry::Point(@pX, @pY, 0)) > radius
```

Comment: @CharlesBrentana cheers pal never saw your edit till now :) I have never worked with these `Geometry Types` in sql server, definitely worth knowing about.